# Is ApplicationCache for FF/IE 10 fully implemented (or implemented correctly)?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-10, application-cache

**Issue:**

Unable to get Fallback resources to get served from applicationCache (Offline cache) when the browser is set to “Work Offline”.

**Environment details:**

- Windows 7 64-bit SP 1
- IE 10 ver. 10.0.9200.16438
- Firefox ver. 18.0.1
- IIS ver 7.5.7600.16385
- .manifest MIME Type is text/cache-manifest

**Manifest details:**

FALLBACK:
/AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew /Sandbox/Car/ AppCacheDemo

**How OFFLINE mode is triggered:**

- IIS Stopped
- Work Offline menu item from the File menu is selected

**Demo Application Details:**

The attached demo consists of 3 pages.

A landing page (/AppCacheDemo/Home/Index) which is the only page that has the manifest file attribute.  As a result of having the manifest attribute, it will automatically be placed in applicationCache.

An online and a corresponding offline version of a page, /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew, /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline respectively.

**Expected Functionality:**

Browser detects presence of manifest attribute when requesting /AppCacheDemo/Home/Index and downloads all resources listed in manifest.

The user clicks on the link that exists on /AppCacheDemo/Home/Index and is redirected to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew

When the browser detects an internet connection, /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew is served to the user.  When an internet connection isn’t detected, /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline is served from applicationCache when requests to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew are made.

**Steps to reproduce in Firefox (actual functionality):**

1. Open FF and clear cache (alt + ctrl + delete).
2. Request about:cache
   a.  Observe that the “Number of entries” listed in Disk/Offline cache are both listed as zero.
3. One a new tab and request /AppCacheDemo/Home/Index
4. Click the Allow button to allow Firefox to store offline data.
5. Return to the about:cache and refresh the page.
   a.  Disk cache Number of entries should be listed as 3 (may be more depending on your environment)
   b.  Offline cache Number of entries should be listed as 3.
6. Click on the Link “List Cache Entries” under the Disk cache section (or open the link in a new tab) and notice there are no entries that point to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew
7. Return to the tab that has /AppCacheDemo/Home/Index open and click on the “Let’s build a new car link”
   a.  You should be redirected to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew
8. Return to about:cache?device=disk and notice that a new entry exists for /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew and it’s Fetch count is listed as 1.
9. Stop IIS
10. Select “Work Offline” menu item from the File Menu
11. Refresh the current page (/AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew)
12. Return to about:cache?device=disk and notice that a new entry exists for /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew and it’s Fetch count is now listed at 2.

Based on the information listed in about:cache?device=disk for /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew, Firefox appears to be serving that version of the page to the user.  I was expecting /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline to get served from applicationCache instead since I have a fallback rule defined in my manifest that states when is requested /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew and no internet connection exists, serve /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline from applicationCache instead.

**Steps to reproduce in Firefox (expected functionality):**

Don’t forget to unselect “Work Offline” prior to executing the steps below.

1. Open FF and clear cache (alt + ctrl + delete).
2. Request about:cache
   a.  Observe that the “Number of entries” listed in Disk/Offline cache are both listed as zero.
3. One a new tab and request /AppCacheDemo/Home/Index
4. Click the Allow button to allow Firefox to store offline data.
5. Return to the about:cache and refresh the page.
   a.  Disk cache Number of entries should be listed as 3 (may be more depending on your environment).
   a.  Offline cache Number of entries should be listed as 3.
6. Click on the Link “List Cache Entries” under the Disk cache section (or open the link in a new tab) and notice there are no entries that point to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew
7. Stop IIS
8. Select “Work Offline” menu item from the File Menu
9. Type /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew in the address bar.
   a.  You should be redirected to /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline.  The URL in the address bar should still read /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew, but the content of the document should be /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline
10. In a new tab, request about:cache?device=disk and notice that a no entires exists for /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew.

Because /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew didn’t exist in Disk cache, FF respected my fallback rule defined in my manifest and served /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline instead.  If I were to

**Testing in IE:**

With the exception of navigating to about:cache, the steps above can more or less be followed.  The difference is that when IE is set to “Work Offline” and request for /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew is made, IE will display a page that has a “This page can't be displayed” message.  If /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline is requested directly, IE will serve the page.  Since a fallback rule is specified in the manifest, I would expect /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline to get served, but it does not.

**Testing in Safari/Chrome:**

Safari/Chrome doesn’t have a “Work Offline” menu item and so there are some additional steps that need to be performed before navigator.onLine is reported as false.  I have to physically unplug my CAT 5 cable and disconnect from any VPN’s in order to put the browser in a truly disconnected state; however, the fallback rules are respected and /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNewOffline is served when /AppCacheDemo/Home/CarNew with no internet connection available.

**AppCacheDemo Project (Microsoft MVC 4 Web Application configured to use IIS):**

http://www.filedropper.com/appcachedemo

Comment: Are you using the correct MIME Type for your manifest?

Comment: text/cache-manifest is what I have IIS serving up .manifest files as.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, testing AppCache in Internet Explorer is a little frustration. It appears that there are some issues with the Work Offline mode that really make debugging a pain. For instance, when I was testing via this method some time back I found that the browser would detect an internet connection, and automatically go online to satisfy the request. This really bugged me.

I [reached out](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/296760770455302144) to [Eric Lawrence](http://www.ericlawrence.com/), author of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (Web Debugger), and past project manager at Microsoft. Eric confirmed that there was indeed a problem. I suspected a tool like Fiddler would remedy these aches, and this was confirmed in a blog post Eric wrote on the Telerik website titled [Testing HTML5 AppCache with Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/blog/13-02-15/testing-html5-appcache-with-fiddler.aspx).

Eric's advice worked for me, and I was able to test AppCache without issue in Internet Explorer using the AutoResponder feature of Fiddler. I hope this helps you as well.